Numerically integrate function with parameters
I have an integrand function f(x) that depends on x and several other parameters, a1, a2, a3, etc. This function could be hard or impossible to integrate symbolically via SymPy; that's why I want to use SciPy for numerical integration, but I am not sure how I can do that to preserve parameters a1, ... and get the result of integration in terms of these parameters.
For example, f(x) = a * x^2, but I "do not know" how to solve it analytically, and after integration from x = 0 to x = 1, I want to get a / 3.
If this is important, I want to keep these parameters because I need to differentiate the expression after integration in terms of these parameters.
So is there a way to do this using existing scipy/numpy instruments, or do I need to create my own numerical integrator?

There is a lot of ambiguity/abstractness in your question, so you're unlikely to get a complete answer from anyone. If your example is f = lambda x, a: a*x**2 and you wanted to numerically differentiate the result of the integral with respect to a, you could write a function that uses finite difference on the numerical integral, i.e. (scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x, a+da), 0, 1) - scip.integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x, a-da), 0, 1))/2/da.

It sounds like what you want is an expression which has symbols like a floating around in it, and that expression is a numerical approximation of an integral, as derived from a quadrature rule. If that's not it, you can help others help you by explaining more about what you want. If that's it, my advice is to use Sympy or any other computer algebra system to write out expressions for whatever rules you want; start with something simple, e.g. Simpson's rule, then maybe try Gaussian integration, or whatever. Then you can differentiate with respect to a or whatever operation you need.


I "do not know" how to solve it analytically, and after integration from x = 0 to x = 1, I want to get a / 3. If this is important, I want to keep these parameters because I need to differentiate the expression after integration in terms of these parameters.

This isn't possible with numerical integration, because numerical differentiation gives you a number as a final result. If you want a symbolic representation, you need symbolic/analytic integration.
Alternatively, if symbolic integration isn't possible, you could use numerical integration followed by numeric differentiation. Numeric differentiation allows you to differentiate a function, even if you have no symbolic representation of it.
Here's a simple example.
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime

def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x ** 2 + b * x ** 3 + a * b

def f_int(a, b):
    result, error = quad(f, 0, 1, args=(a, b))
    return result

def f_int_jacobian(a, b):
    return approx_fprime([a, b], lambda p: f_int(p[0], p[1]), epsilon=1e-8)

# Evaluate integral at a=1 b=1
f_int(1, 1)

# Take jacobian/gradient of function with respect to a and b at a=1, b=1
f_int_jacobian(1, 1)

There's a potential issue with this approach, though. When you numerically differentiate a function like this, the integration has some error bound, controlled by the epsabs and epsrel parameters to quad. (See docs.) If your integration is wrong by 1e-8 for one evaluation, then the error when differentiating will be 1e-8/1e-8, which will make the slope be wrong by 1. This means that small errors will be magnified. I recommend you tune epsabs, epsrel, and epsilon to avoid this.


I need to differentiate the expression after integration in terms of these parameters.

Why not differentiate before integrating rather than after?
See the Leibniz rule but if your limits don't depend on the parameters then it really is as simple as differentiating the integrand:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule
You can do ask SymPy to apply the Leibniz rule and then calculate the integral numerically after e.g.:
In [20]: a, x = symbols('a, x')

In [21]: Integral(a*x**2, (x, 0, 1))
Out[21]: 
1        
⌠        
⎮    2   
⎮ a⋅x  dx
⌡        
0        

In [22]: Integral(a*x**2, (x, 0, 1)).diff(a)
Out[22]: 
1      
⌠      
⎮  2   
⎮ x  dx
⌡      
0      

In [23]: Integral(a*x**2, (x, 0, 1)).diff(a).evalf()
Out[23]: 0.333333333333333

In this case after differentiating the integral didn't depend on a but more likely it would and we would need to substitute a value for numerical integration:
In [24]: Integral(a**2*x**2, (x, 0, 1)).diff(a).subs(a, 1).evalf()
Out[24]: 0.666666666666667

